# As Black, what is the fastest way to beat Gnu Chess on easy mode?

Tags: engines, puzzles, solving

This is more of a puzzle. As far as I can ascertain, Gnu-Chess on easy mode always plays the same movesm What is the least amount of moves required to beat Gnu Chess on easy mode? Just to clarify, you are playing as Black, Gnu Chess is playing as White.

[image]

Comment: Does it play with the same strength (making the same moves) on all hardware?

Comment: A 2006 core 2 duo laptop and a 2013 intel i5 laptop both play exactly the same.

Comment: White played only one move... You can't refute a correct opening ( this one is correct one, though **unambitious** ) with a series of forced moves. If I would have to try, I would respond with `1...d5`.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff Thank you for your comment. I am afraid you misunderstand; We are talking about a chess engine which on easy, always starts this way, and always plays the same thereafter. If you say, find a way to beat this engine in 60 moves, you can use that method on any other computer with this chess engine to beat him using the same 60 moves. I hope this clarified the puzzle for you.

Comment: So, if I play `1...d5` it will respond the same on every computer? What about following moves? Does it play other 10+ moves the same on every computer? If so then there might be a way to solve this...

Comment: Can you give us a download link? The one I found always starts with `1.e4`, so I can't help you now...

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff I am on ubuntu, and I am just using the one from the repos. 
akiva@Akiva-ThinkPad:~/Music/Podcasts$ gnuchess --version
GNU Chess 6.1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the fastest way that I've found.

```
[Event "?"]
[Site "?"]
[Date "2014.07.12"]
[Round "?"]
[White "?"]
[Black "?"]
[FEN ""]

1. Nc3 d5 2. Nf3 d4 3. Ne4 b6 4. d3 f5 5. Ne4g5 h6 6. Nh3 g5 7. Bd2 g4 8. Nhg1 gxf3 9. Nxf3 Nc6 10. Bf4 h5 11. h3 Bh6 12. Ng5 e5 13. Bxe5 Nxe5 14. Nf3 Nxf3+ 15. gxf3 Nf6 16. Rg1 Rg8 17. Rxg8+ Nxg8 18. Bg2 Bb7 19. a4 a5 20. Kf1 Nf6 21. Qe1 Nd5 22. Rd1 Nf4 23. e4 Qe7 24. e5 O-O-O 25. Ra1 Rg8 26. Bh1 Qg5 27. Rb1 Qg1#
```

Answer (score -1):

here how I win against gnu chess version 6.2.2 as black:

1. Nf3  d5
2. d4  Nf6
3. c4  e6
4. Nc3 c6
5. e3  Nbd7
6. Bd3  dxc4
7. Bxc4 b5
8. Bd3  a6
9. O-O  Bb7
10. e4 Qc7
11. dxe6  fxe6
12. Bc2 c4
13. Ng5  Nc5
14. Qf3  Bd6
15. Qh3  O-O-O
16. Re1  Kb8
17. Nf3  e5
18. Bg5  Nd3
19. Bxd3  Rxd3
20. Qh4  bxa4
21. Nxa4  Bb4
22. Bxf6  Bxe1
23. Rxe1  gxf6
24. Qxf6  Re8
25. Nc3  Rd6
26. Qg5  Rg6
27. Qe3  Rd8
28. Nd5  Bxd5
29. exd5  Rb6
30. d6  Rbxd6
31. Nxe5  Rd5
32. h3  Qc5
33. Qc3  Qd4
34. Nxc4  Qxc3
35. bxc3  Rd1
36. Kf1 Rxe1+
37. Kxe1  Rd3
38. Nb6+  Kb7
39. Na4  Rd8
40. c4  Rd4
41. Nb2 Kc5
42. f4  Rd8
43. Ke4 Rb8
44. Nd3+  Kxc4
45. f5
    {White resigns} 0-1

Comment: Why add an answer when there's already someone who shared a faster way? Welcome to our community by the way!